# Beta function for $U(N)$ Yang-MIlls?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, renormalization, yang-mills

What is the one-loop beta function $\beta(g)$ for $U(N)$ pure Yang-Mills? I expect it to behave rather differently than $SU(N)$, since when $N=1$ we have electrodynamics, for which $\beta(e)=0$. As a Lie algebra, $U(N)\cong SU(N)\times U(1)$. We know $SU(N)$ Yang-Mills to be asymptotically free at one-loop, but I know that $U(1)$ may spoil this.

Comment: Perturbatively you are only sensitive to the Lie algebra, which in this case is a direct sum, so you just get the usual beta-function for the $su(N)$ part and the trivial one for $u(1)$. (Since the Lie algebra is not simple, you have two couplings for the $F^2$ term, not one.)

Comment: @PeterKravchuk Thank you for your comment. I'm not sure what you mean by two couplings, how does that arise?

Comment: $F_{\mu\nu}$ is valued in Lie algebra. For simple Lie algebras, the only quadratic in $F$ gauge invariant that you can write is $\frac{1}{g^2}\mathrm{tr}\,FF$ (more precisely, the Killing form). For semisimple algebras this is not true anymore. In this particular case you can split $F$ into a $U(1)$ component $F_{U(1)}$ and an $SU(N)$ component $F_{SU(N)}$ according the decomposition of the Lie algebra. Then you can write both $\frac{1}{g_{U(1)}^2}F_{U(1)}F_{U(1)}$ and $\frac{1}{g_{SU(N)}^2}\mathrm{tr}\, F_{SU(N)}F_{SU(N)}$, with different couplings.

Comment: To be more accurate, this algebra is not semisimple, it is reductive. Still, the point in the above comment stands.